# Desktop network throttling for simulating bad connections to web applications on Windows

Tags: windows, networking

Any recommendations of Windows software I can use to accomplish simulating poor internet connections for the purposes of testing a web application?

Thanks

**Note**

I've heard of Linux network kernel modules that provide this kind of poor connection simulations but I need something for Windows.

Comment: Duplicates http://serverfault.com/questions/2014/what-tools-can-i-use-to-simulate-a-wan-for-http-traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the duplicate question [NetLimiter](http://netlimiter.com/) seems like Windows option.